# Get full XPath itself from partial in Selenium Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I want to get the text 43,009,500(which is not defined) next to AAAAAA(which text is defined, but the xpath depends on the case)

AAAAAA's XPath : /html/body/table[3]/tbody/tr[10]/td[1]

43,009,500's XPath : /html/body/table[3]/tbody/tr[10]/td[2]

How can I get the full XPath of AAAAAA?

```html
<tr>
      <td width="247" height="20" colspan="2">AAAAAA</td>
      <td width="105" height="20" align="RIGHT" style="font-size:10pt;">43,009,500</td>
      <td width="105" height="20" align="RIGHT" style="font-size:10pt;">-</td>
      <td width="104" height="20" align="RIGHT" style="font-size:10pt;">50,009,500</td>
      <td width="104" height="20" align="CENTER" style="font-size:10pt;">-</td>
    </tr>
```

```
x = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[text()='AAAAAA").click()
driver.finfind_element_by_xpath(x[:-2]+'2]').text

NoSuchElementException                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-139-6295b210748f> in <module>
      6 driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='BBBBBB']").click()
----> 7 x = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[text()='AAAAAA")
      8 driver.finfind_element_by_xpath(x[:-2]+'2]').text
```

Comment: try using xpath `//td[text()='AAAAAA"]/following-sibling::td[1]`

Comment: @RichEdwards Thanks, but it got Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:

Comment: Check if this element is behind an iframe.

Comment: @Sureshmani yes, it is behind an iframe, but the same error occurred. driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='BBBBBB']").click()
time.sleep(1)
src = driver.find_element_by_id("ifrm").get_attribute("src")
driver.get(src)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[text()='AAAAAA']/following-sibling::td[1]").text

Comment: @RichEdwards AAAAA is actually "&nbsp;Ⅵ. AAAAA (Ⅳ-Ⅴ)" I think this makes error. Your answer is right. Thank you.

Comment: @RichEdwards driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[text()[contains(.,'AAAAAA')]]/following-sibling::td[1]").text

Comment: @Sureshmani driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[text()[contains(.,'AAAAAA')]]/following-sibling::td[1]").text I found .Thank you.

Comment: No problem dude. Happy to help :-)